# Cloud Function - how to avoid nested promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing Cloud Functions very first time in NodeJS and that's working very well, but whenever I tried to deploy I got a warning like this:

> warning Avoid nesting promises promise/no-nesting (line 9)

I tried to get rid of this, but there are some issues which I need to resolve:

```
exports.updateUserCount = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun(context => {
    return admin.database().ref('/servers').once('value').then(snapshot =>{

        var ips = {}
        snapshot.val().forEach( (server, i) => { ips[server.label] = server.ipv4[0] })

        var promises = snapshot.val().map( (server, index) => {
            let sftp = new Client()
            return Promise.all([sftp, server.label, index, sftp.connect({ host : server.ipv4[0], port : '22', username : 'user_name', password : '*********' })])
            .then( values => {
                return Promise.all([values[0], values[0].get('/etc/openvpn/server/openvpn-status.log'), values[1], values[2]])
            }).then( data => {
                data[0].end()
                if (data[1]) {
                    let count = countWords(data[1].toString(),"client_list") - 1
                    console.log(count, `users connected now with ${data[2]} ${data[3]}`)

                    return Promise.all([ count, admin.database().ref(snapshot.child(index.toString()).ref).update({ userCount : count }) ])
                }
                console.log('file not found')
            return false
            }).catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
        })

        console.log(`array ${JSON.stringify(ips)}`)
        return Promise.all(promises)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

If I try to put other code outside of nesting I can't get instance of `sftp` and it can't be declared globally because each `sftp` is connected to and having configs of different servers.

Any help will be appreciated and thanks is advance.

Comment: Did you do a web search for that error message?  It comes up a lot.

Comment: async/await usually helps in such cases

Comment: @DougStevenson yes I did but not found any suitable answer I'm searching from 1 week.

Comment: @JaromandaX can you refer any example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575743/nodejs-how-to-avoid-nested-then-when-using-async-await

Comment: Don't stress too much over that particular warning. It can be happily ignored. There are good reasons for nesting promises, not least of which is to [benefit from closures in order to access previous results in a .then() chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250687/3478010), as is the case here. Once you've come to terms with nesting, the need to pass values through disappears and the code will become more readable (again?).

Comment: async/await was designed mainly to avoid this problem called callback hell